# How to Create Event/Agent to monitor report distribution

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

We have some Cognos reports that are distributed via email; however, they are not always successfully sent.  I'm trying to use Event Studio to create a Job/Agent that will monitor these reports and report the distribution status, but am not having any luck.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLAZS.png) a sample view of our reports.  When I open Event Studio, it prompts me to select a package.  That said, [there are no 'packages' or reports available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK77q.png).  All of these directories and reports are in a single package but I can't open that main package in Event Studio.  I've been informed that I have Admin rights, so I don't think its an issue with privileges.  From [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLAZS.png), I can click 'New Package' and it [directs me to select a Connection (our data sources are an Oracle database)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9lG5.png); however, there are no connections available.  I'm Not sure what to do here.  Any guidance insight into solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Cognos are you using?

Comment: Hello.  Thanks for the response.  I am on 10.2